# Power in circuit fading away after a few seconds

Tags: led, raspberry-pi, led-strip, breadboard

I have an RGB LED strip connected to a power source via a breadboard with three MOSFETs that are controlled by a Raspberry Pi. I followed [this tutorial](https://dordnung.de/raspberrypi-ledstrip/#!%2F) to build exactly this setup:

[image]

This worked before, but I disassembled everything and moved to a new place. Since I put it together again, it doesn't work any more. When I connect the power supply, nothing happens. If I connect it with interchanged poles for a while, then disconnect it and reconnect it again, with the poles connected like in the picture, than the LED glows for a few seconds and then slowly fades out. 
The power adapter is connected like this:
[image]

The strip originally came with an IR-controllable power supply. If I use that, the LEDs work:
[image]

I double checked that all wires are connected as shown in the image and as it worked before. Can anybody tell me, which pieces could be responsible for my problem and if there might be damaged hardware?

Comment: You should replace the two purple wires on the power supply connector with red and black wires, so you can easily tell that you have the power supply connected with the correct polarity.

Comment: Use what works then. Seems like thermal overloaded supply from insufficient Watt rating

Comment: Just a tip: Fritzing should be able to give you a *schematic* diagram instead of the *wiring* diagram. The schematic tells us what the circuit is supposed to do. The wiring diagram doesn't so they are generally frowned upon on this site.

Comment: the piece that is responsible is sitting on top of your neck. you made a mistake when you reconnected everything

Answer (score 1):

If it works for a few seconds then stops, and disconnecting and reconnecting it after a few seconds, it tends to be a power supply in current overload or short circuit protection mode. If the leds work with the original controller, then it's your circuit.

So replace the power supply. If that doesn't work, recreate your circuit with new mosfets. If it still doesnt, check your code or raspberry pi.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the answer but breadboards are not reliable. TO pins are larger than Dupont pins and the contact may be bad between them when you put them on the same line. TO pins are not perfectly breadboard compatible.